# How to disable antialiasing for a widget?

Tags: qt, qt5

For reasons that are out of my control a widget has to be rendered without antialiasing. It used to be painted all by in house written spaghetti code with render hints:

```
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, false);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, false);
```

Now I'm rewriting that widget as inherited from QWidget and using QTs own QLabel, QButton and style-sheet. Is there a way to disable antialiasing for a widget and it's children?

Comment: It's only about text/font antialiasing? If yes, QFont's `setStyleStrategy(QFont::NoAntialias);`  could be a solution.

Comment: I'm afraid it shall affects widget borders as well. For the font you mean putting 
```auto f = font();
    f.setStyleStrategy(QFont::NoAntialias);
    setFont(f);``` Into each children widget constructor?

Comment: Yes, but (depending on your application), maybe you can get away setting the font for the whole application at once with `QApplication::setFont()`  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setFont.
But of course if you also need to set this for the borders, then (at least by itself) doesn't solve your issue...